# Linux Kernel Error

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I got the same errors on these lines

```
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

line 49:  for (current = root; current != NULL; ptr = current) {

line 50:  current =current->link[res];

line 75:  for (current = bf; current != newnode; res = link_dir[++i]) {

line 80:  current = current->link[res];

line 167: current = root;

line 192: current = current->link[res];
```

How can I fix this?

I am using kernel version 2.6.32-24-generic

It is my one of function and above four errors are from this function...
It is an insertion function of AVL tree.

```
static void insertion (char value[]) {
        struct AVLTree_Node *bf, *parent_bf, *subtree, *temp;
        struct AVLTree_Node *current, *parent, *newnode, *ptr;
        int res = 0,i=0 ,num=100, compareLimit = 100; 
        char link_dir[32];

        if (!root) {
                root = createNode(value);
                return;
        }

        bf = parent_bf;
        parent_bf = root;
        // find the location for inserting the new node
        for (current = root; current != NULL; ptr = current) {
             current =current->link[res];
                num = strcmp(value,current->data);
                if (num == 0) {
                        printk(KERN_INFO "Cannot insert duplicates!!\n");
                        return;
                }
                int result = strncmp(value,current->data, compareLimit);
                if(result > 0) 
                        res = 1;  
                else if(result <= 0) 
                        res =0;
                parent = current;

                if (current->bfactor != 0) {
                        bf = current;
                        parent_bf = ptr;
                        i = 0;
                }
                link_dir[i++] = res;
        }
        // create the new node 
        newnode = createNode(value);
        parent->link[res] = newnode;
        res = link_dir[i = 0];
        // updating the height balance after insertion 
        for (current = bf; current != newnode; res = link_dir[++i]) {
                if (res == 0)
                        current->bfactor--;
                else
                        current->bfactor++;
                current = current->link[res];
        }

        // right sub-tree 
        if (bf->bfactor == 2) {
                printk(KERN_INFO "bfactor = 2\n");
                temp = bf->link[1];
                if (temp->bfactor == 1) {                   
                        subtree = temp;
                        bf->link[1] = temp->link[0];
                        temp->link[0] = bf;
                        temp->bfactor = bf->bfactor = 0;
                } else {
                        subtree = temp->link[0];
                        temp->link[0] = subtree->link[1];
                        subtree->link[1] = temp;
                        bf->link[1] = subtree->link[0];
                        subtree->link[0] = bf;
                        // update balance factors 
                        if (subtree->bfactor == -1) {
                                bf->bfactor = 0;
                                temp->bfactor = 1;
                        } else if (subtree->bfactor == 0) {
                                bf->bfactor = 0;
                                temp->bfactor = 0;
                        } else if (subtree->bfactor == 1) {
                                bf->bfactor = -1;
                                temp->bfactor = 0;
                        }
                        subtree->bfactor = 0;
                }
        // left sub-tree 
        } else if (bf->bfactor == -2) {
                temp = bf->link[0];
                if (temp->bfactor == -1) {

                         // single rotation(SR) right

                        subtree = temp;
                        bf->link[0] = temp->link[1];
                        temp->link[1] = bf;
                        temp->bfactor = bf->bfactor = 0;
                } else {
                        // double rotation - (SR left + SR right)

                        subtree = temp->link[1];
                        temp->link[1] = subtree->link[0];
                        subtree->link[0] = temp;
                        bf->link[0] = subtree->link[1];
                        subtree->link[1] = bf;
                        // update balance factors 
                        if (subtree->bfactor == -1) {
                                bf->bfactor = 1;
                                temp->bfactor = 0;
                        } else if (subtree->bfactor == 0) {
                                bf->bfactor = 0;
                                temp->bfactor = 0;
                        } else if (subtree->bfactor == 1) {
                                bf->bfactor = 0;
                                temp->bfactor = -1;
                        }
                        subtree->bfactor = 0;
                }
        } else {
                return;
        }

        if (bf == root) {
                root = subtree;
                return;
        }
        if (bf != parent_bf->link[0]) {
                parent_bf->link[1] = subtree;
        } else {
                parent_bf->link[0] = subtree;
        }
        return;
}
```

Comment: `Linux kernel error` What you do with kernel? And how you get this error? I think you get compilation error in compiling some code.So post code.

Comment: Please put more information here as it is hard to answer when you did not supply sufficient information like what you are doing and when this occurs, which kernel version you compile etc.

Comment: Thanks for Reply Sir..
Please see the post again..

Comment: I have not been developing in C for 15 years so I do not feel able to answer you. The code looks ok. The compiler issue seems like 'current' is not variable. But it is defined above. Could it clash with something?

Comment: When I run this in C, it looks ok but when I compile it as a kernel module it shows such errors...

Comment: @MuhammadNouman Where is root declared?  How is it declared?  Can you try using other variable names other than 'current' and 'root'.  Also, value should be a char* not a char[] and you might want to pick another variable name for that too.

Comment: Root is declared as struct AVLTree_Node *root = NULL;
It is declared globally..
And you said that I pass a char* to insertion function instead of char[] ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`current` is a macro that [expands](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/include/asm/current.h) into a function call:

```c
static __always_inline struct task_struct *get_current(void)
{
        return this_cpu_read_stable(current_task);
}

#define current get_current()
```

Use some other variable name.